# How can I pass call to a function?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I need to pass a function into another function and call it there. I use the following code:

```
namespace DelegateTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public class MySampleClass
        {
            public void click(string param)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(param + " click!");
            }

            public void flick(string param)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(param + " flick!");
            }
        }

        public static delegate void EventToWait(string param);

        public static void waitFor(EventToWait myEvent, string param)
        {
            // here is a **very** complex loop, which i would like wipe from main() function
            myEvent(param);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MySampleClass sc = new MySampleClass();
            EventToWait ev1 = sc.click;
            EventToWait ev2 = sc.flick;

            waitFor(ev1, "Button_1");
            waitFor(ev2, "Button_2");

            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

But my compiler says, that delegate can't be static. How could I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, simply remove the `static` keyword:

```
public delegate void EventToWait(string param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can declare:

```
public static void waitFor(Action<string> myEvent, string param)
```

and in your main call:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MySampleClass sc = new MySampleClass();
            EventToWait ev1 = sc.click;
            EventToWait ev2 = sc.flick;

            waitFor((k)=>sc.click(k), "Button_1");
            waitFor((k)=>sc.flick(k), "Button_2");

            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

this avoid the needing of declaring the delegate.